# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) func prepare

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case toProductIdentifier: let destination = segue.destination as? ProductViewController
        destination?.configureProduct(for: products[selectedRowIndex.row])
    default: break
    }
}
```

So I getting this error in line destination?.configureProduct(for: products[selectedRowIndex.row])

And here is a code for func configureProduct but I Don't really think that problem in this func

```
func configureProduct(for product: instockProduct) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let brand = product.brand["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.productBrandLabel.text = brand.uppercased()
        self.productNameLabel.text = product.name
        self.productPriceLabel.text = product.price.stringValue
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `price` variable  , and what value is `selectedRowIndex.row` ?

Comment: price - number. But when I comment whole code in configureProduct func error not changing

Comment: Are you sure that `selectedRowIndex.row` is not some negative number?

Comment: maybe it is because I can't even print it out. Let me check

Comment: So what I'm doing.

I have var selectedRowIndex = IndexPath() and than func

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(products[indexPath.row].name)
        selectedRowIndex = indexPath
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: toProductIdentifier, sender: nil)
    }

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak, sorry for bad format of code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the outlets are not connected (yet) in the destination view controller during `prepare(for segue`.

You need a temporary property in `ProductViewController` and configure the outlets in `viewDidLoad`

```
var product : Product! // replace Product with the real type

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let brand = product.brand["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.productBrandLabel.text = brand.uppercased()
        self.productNameLabel.text = product.name
        self.productPriceLabel.text = product.price.stringValue
    }
}
```

and replace `prepare(for segue` with

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
        case toProductIdentifier: 
           let destination = segue.destination as! ProductViewController
           let cell = sender as! ProductCollectionViewCell
           let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)!
           destination.product = products[indexPath.item]
        default: break
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Obviously you connected the **cell** to the segue rather than the controller. In this case the `cell` is passed in the `sender` parameter and `didSelectItemAt` is not being called. Delete `selectedRowIndex` and delete also the entire `didSelectItemAt` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    print(product.name) 
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)         
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: toProductIdentifier, sender: product) 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error https://ibb.co/0Gd68MV

Comment: Did you change `didSelectItemAt` as suggested: `......sender: product)`?

Comment: yes, checked it twice

Comment: If the `product` object is passed in the `sender` parameter then the error must not occur.

Comment: Maybe you know how to make right assignment to selectedRowIndex? I'm assigning value but idk why first calling prepare func and then didSelect. That's why it throws error. 1st click - selectedRowIndex = [] indexPath = [0, 1]. 2nd click - selectedRowIndex = [0, 1] indexPath = [0, 0] and so on

Comment: With my solution `selectedRowIndex` is not needed.

Comment: @vadian is right that you also do not have connected outlets in `ProductViewController` since `IBOutlets` are connected only after `viewDidLayout` function.  Stick to his solution so you do not have to use `selectedRowIndex`.

Comment: I still have same error that I mentioned in my first comment. And yes, product object is passed in the sender parameter

Comment: That's the description of error (let product = sender as! instockProduct) - Could not cast value of type 'LP.ProductCollectionViewCell' (0x10e93b178) to 'LP.instockProduct' (0x10e8f6b68).

Comment: I see, this changes a lot of things. Please see the edit.

Comment: Maybe you know how to fix this? https://ibb.co/TqXN4q4

Comment: The line assumes that there is a property `collectionView` representing the UICollectionView instance. You can also try `let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Changed line to let indexPath = productCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)! and now all working perfect, ty!

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating `indexPath` with empty value `indexPath = IndexPath()`, and propably not using `indexPath` that is provided to you by tableView, therefore the error. I reproduced in Playground your code with simplified example and get the same error.

Try checking if the `didSelectItemAt` function is triggered properly and you are truly assigning to `selectedRowIndex` variable the indexPath returned from `UITableView` and not using the precreated `IndexPath()` value.

[image: recreated your error]

Comment: I'm assigning value but idk why first calling prepare func and then didSelect. That's why it throws error. 1st click - selectedRowIndex = []
indexPath = [0, 1]. 2nd click - selectedRowIndex = [0, 1]
indexPath = [0, 0] and so on